# What is the correct response to cross-posted questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

I occasionally see questions that have been cross-posted. For example, [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135259/disable-discrete-gpu-in-single-user-mode-install-partition) was [also posted on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/769826/disable-discrete-gpu-in-single-user-mode-osx-10-10-install-partition) at approximately the same time.

In the past, I usually flag such cross-posts with a custom reason, but is this the best way to deal with it? Recently, I've been adding comments to the effect of…

> Please don't cross post :) If you don't get the response desired from [xpost], request a moderator migrate it rather than reposting the question yourself.

How should cross posts be dealt with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general commenting and flagging are both valid options in these situations.